# How to dynamically create a class?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection.emit, dynamic-class-creation

I have a class which looks like this:

```
public class Field
{
    public string FieldName;
    public string FieldType;
}
```

And an object `List<Field>` with values:

```
{"EmployeeID","int"},
{"EmployeeName","String"},
{"Designation","String"}
```

I want to create a class that looks like this:

```
Class DynamicClass
{
    int EmployeeID,
    String EmployeeName,
    String Designation
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

I want this to be generated at runtime. I don't want a physical CS file residing in my filesystem.

Comment: Do You want to use that class in runtime or only generate file ?

Comment: I want this to be generated in runtime. I dont want a physical CS file residing in my filesystem. Sorry for not mentioning that earlier.

Comment: Can you give us a rough idea of what do you intend to **do** with this class?

Comment: @Justin implement runtime-resolved interfaces, for instance.

Comment: One could feed it to `System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory<MyDynamicInterface>`

Comment: I am not sure why do you need a dynamic `class` if you say `anonymous object` that makes some sense. But what is the purpose of a dynamic class here, i mean what are you attempting to achieve ? Plz see my answer of `DynamicEntity` here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75920247/3057246

Answer (score 345, accepted):

Yes, you can use `System.Reflection.Emit` namespace for this. It is not straight forward if you have no experience with it, but it is certainly possible.

**Edit:** This code might be flawed, but it will give you the general idea and hopefully off to a good start towards the goal.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

namespace TypeBuilderNamespace
{
    public static class MyTypeBuilder
    {
        public static void CreateNewObject()
        {
            var myType = CompileResultType();
            var myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
        }
        public static Type CompileResultType()
        {
            TypeBuilder tb = GetTypeBuilder();
            ConstructorBuilder constructor = tb.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName);

            // NOTE: assuming your list contains Field objects with fields FieldName(string) and FieldType(Type)
            foreach (var field in yourListOfFields)
                CreateProperty(tb, field.FieldName, field.FieldType);

            Type objectType = tb.CreateType();
            return objectType;
        }

        private static TypeBuilder GetTypeBuilder()
        {
            var typeSignature = "MyDynamicType";
            var an = new AssemblyName(typeSignature);
            AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(an, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
            ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MainModule");
            TypeBuilder tb = moduleBuilder.DefineType(typeSignature,
                    TypeAttributes.Public |
                    TypeAttributes.Class |
                    TypeAttributes.AutoClass |
                    TypeAttributes.AnsiClass |
                    TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit |
                    TypeAttributes.AutoLayout,
                    null);
            return tb;
        }

        private static void CreateProperty(TypeBuilder tb, string propertyName, Type propertyType)
        {
            FieldBuilder fieldBuilder = tb.DefineField("_" + propertyName, propertyType, FieldAttributes.Private);

            PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = tb.DefineProperty(propertyName, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, propertyType, null);
            MethodBuilder getPropMthdBldr = tb.DefineMethod("get_" + propertyName, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);
            ILGenerator getIl = getPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();

            getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
            getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            MethodBuilder setPropMthdBldr =
                tb.DefineMethod("set_" + propertyName,
                  MethodAttributes.Public |
                  MethodAttributes.SpecialName |
                  MethodAttributes.HideBySig,
                  null, new[] { propertyType });

            ILGenerator setIl = setPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
            Label modifyProperty = setIl.DefineLabel();
            Label exitSet = setIl.DefineLabel();

            setIl.MarkLabel(modifyProperty);
            setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);

            setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
            setIl.MarkLabel(exitSet);
            setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getPropMthdBldr);
            propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setPropMthdBldr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome!! Can you also tell me how to create an object of the type returned by the CompileResultType() Method?

Comment: You can use System.Activator for that. I'll update the answer with an example.

Comment: Note also that you will have to use reflection to examine, read and update fields in your dynamic type. If you want intellisense and no reflection, you have to have a static base class or interface that your dynamic class inherits from and can be casted to. In that case you can modify GetTypeBuilder() method and change moduleBuilder.DefineType call to include the static type as the last parameter (is null now)

Comment: can someone explain how to use the object after its created

Comment: @bugz use the code above to create the class, then in the base class you can add this method:

public void SetValue<T>(string name, T value) {
  GetType().GetProperty(name).SetValue(this, value);
}

Comment: is there a way to check if it already exists in the assembly before calling

Comment: @user2330270 Yes you can use Type.GetType(string) see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499593/c-sharp-how-to-check-if-namespace-class-or-method-exists-in-c)

Comment: Apart from what @danijels suggested to use a base interface is there any other way to pass this newly generated type as the base type for generic class? i.e. T in List<T>

Comment: @danijels This code worked well for me, but I also want to create the physical class file for this class, which can be used in project. How can I do this?

Comment: @mohammad-sohail you should have a look at some of the other answers for that. Not what OP asked for, though

Comment: Hi what if we want to update the PropertyInfo instead of creating a new Property

Comment: how can i use this runtime class in list<T> use it?

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I just want to add that you can also work with such types using the dynamic keyword, although if you know member names at compile time, it is better to have them implement an interface or inherit a base class and access through that.  Still... completeness.

Comment: you seems really good with IL could u please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48160989/convert-loop-to-one-delegate?noredirect=1#comment83301610_48160989

Comment: how do i unregister / remove the newly defined type? im trying to create a lot of classes on the fly. Want them GC'ed after use.

Comment: we need to use `AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndCollect` to improve memory consumption.

Comment: Will that return a dynamic class or a generic class that preserves type safety?

Comment: I have used this in .net core and class is created but its showing value of namespace is null

Answer (score 77):

It will take some work, but is certainly not impossible.

What I have done is:

- Create a C# source in a string (no need to write out to a file),
- Run it through the `Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider` (CompileAssemblyFromSource)
- Find the generated Type
- And create an instance of that Type (`Activator.CreateInstance`)

This way you can deal with the C# code you already know, instead of having to emit MSIL.

But this works best if your class implements some interface (or is derived from some baseclass), else how is the calling code (read: compiler) to know about that class that will be generated at runtime?

Comment: Might want to see this discussion: [reflection-emit-vs-codedom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366921/reflection-emit-vs-codedom)

Comment: @nawfal , ashwnacharya, wanted to generate dynamically at runtime its class with its members originally contained into a list. I don't think putting it into a file even generated at runtime would be a good performance solution.

Answer (score 46):

You can also dynamically create a class by using [DynamicObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
public class DynamicClass : DynamicObject
{
    private Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<Type, object>> _fields;

    public DynamicClass(List<Field> fields)
    {
        _fields = new Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<Type, object>>();
        fields.ForEach(x => _fields.Add(x.FieldName,
            new KeyValuePair<Type, object>(x.FieldType, null)));
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        if (_fields.ContainsKey(binder.Name))
        {
            var type = _fields[binder.Name].Key;
            if (value.GetType() == type)
            {
                _fields[binder.Name] = new KeyValuePair<Type, object>(type, value);
                return true;
            }
            else throw new Exception("Value " + value + " is not of type " + type.Name);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = _fields[binder.Name].Value;
        return true;
    }
}
```

I store all class fields in a dictionary `_fields` together with their types and values. The both methods are to can get or set value to some of the properties. You must use the `dynamic` keyword to create an instance of this class.

The usage with your example:

```
var fields = new List<Field>() { 
    new Field("EmployeeID", typeof(int)),
    new Field("EmployeeName", typeof(string)),
    new Field("Designation", typeof(string)) 
};

dynamic obj = new DynamicClass(fields);

//set
obj.EmployeeID = 123456;
obj.EmployeeName = "John";
obj.Designation = "Tech Lead";

obj.Age = 25;             //Exception: DynamicClass does not contain a definition for 'Age'
obj.EmployeeName = 666;   //Exception: Value 666 is not of type String

//get
Console.WriteLine(obj.EmployeeID);     //123456
Console.WriteLine(obj.EmployeeName);   //John
Console.WriteLine(obj.Designation);    //Tech Lead
```

**Edit:** And here is how looks my class `Field`:

```
public class Field
{
    public Field(string name, Type type)
    {
        this.FieldName = name;
        this.FieldType = type;
    }

    public string FieldName;

    public Type FieldType;
}
```

Comment: I liked this approach till I needed to initialize the fields with the constructor. i.e `dynamic obj = new DynamicClass(fields){EmployeeId=123456;EmployeeName = "John"; Designation = "Tech Lead";}` It would really be great doing this.

Comment: Also note that this approach forces boxing for all value type fields.

Answer (score 28):

I know i reopen this old task but with c# 4.0 this task is absolutely painless.

```
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
expando.EmployeeID=42;
expando.Designation="unknown";
expando.EmployeeName="curt"

//or more dynamic
AddProperty(expando, "Language", "English");
```

for more see
https://www.oreilly.com/learning/building-c-objects-dynamically

Comment: Yes, but you lose type safety here. Can we do something similar while preserving type safety?

Comment: use in conjunction with https://stackoverflow.com/a/4938442/3588010

Answer (score 18):

I don't know the intended usage of such dynamic classes, and code generation and run time compilation can be done, but takes some effort.
Maybe [Anonymous Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) would help you, something like:

```
var v = new { EmployeeID = 108, EmployeeName = "John Doe" };
```

Comment: You can't hard code the field names. He's providing them with his `Field.FieldName`. Having to hard code the field names defeats the purpose. If you have to do that, you might as well create the class.

Comment: I've used these for years and forgot what they were called, Anonymous Types.  Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

As [Hans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3862344/171846) suggested, you can use Roslyn to dynamically create classes.

Full source:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace RoslynDemo1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var fields = new List<Field>()
            {
                new Field("EmployeeID","int"),
                new Field("EmployeeName","String"),
                new Field("Designation","String")
            };

            var employeeClass = CreateClass(fields, "Employee");

            dynamic employee1 = Activator.CreateInstance(employeeClass);
            employee1.EmployeeID = 4213;
            employee1.EmployeeName = "Wendy Tailor";
            employee1.Designation = "Engineering Manager";

            dynamic employee2 = Activator.CreateInstance(employeeClass);
            employee2.EmployeeID = 3510;
            employee2.EmployeeName = "John Gibson";
            employee2.Designation = "Software Engineer";

            Console.WriteLine($"{employee1.EmployeeName}");
            Console.WriteLine($"{employee2.EmployeeName}");

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static Type CreateClass(List<Field> fields, string newClassName, string newNamespace = "Magic")
        {
            var fieldsCode = fields
                                .Select(field => $"public {field.FieldType} {field.FieldName};")
                                .ToString(Environment.NewLine);

            var classCode = $@"
                using System;

                namespace {newNamespace}
                {{
                    public class {newClassName}
                    {{
                        public {newClassName}()
                        {{
                        }}

                        {fieldsCode}
                    }}
                }}
            ".Trim();

            classCode = FormatUsingRoslyn(classCode);


            var assemblies = new[]
            {
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location),
            };

            /*
            var assemblies = AppDomain
                        .CurrentDomain
                        .GetAssemblies()
                        .Where(a => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Location))
                        .Select(a => MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(a.Location))
                        .ToArray();
            */

            var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(classCode);

            var compilation = CSharpCompilation
                                .Create(newNamespace)
                                .AddSyntaxTrees(syntaxTree)
                                .AddReferences(assemblies)
                                .WithOptions(new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary));

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var result = compilation.Emit(ms);
                //compilation.Emit($"C:\\Temp\\{newNamespace}.dll");

                if (result.Success)
                {
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(ms.ToArray());

                    var newTypeFullName = $"{newNamespace}.{newClassName}";

                    var type = assembly.GetType(newTypeFullName);
                    return type;
                }
                else
                {
                    IEnumerable<Diagnostic> failures = result.Diagnostics.Where(diagnostic =>
                        diagnostic.IsWarningAsError ||
                        diagnostic.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Error);

                    foreach (Diagnostic diagnostic in failures)
                    {
                        Console.Error.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", diagnostic.Id, diagnostic.GetMessage());
                    }

                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

        public static string FormatUsingRoslyn(string csCode)
        {
            var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(csCode);
            var root = tree.GetRoot().NormalizeWhitespace();
            var result = root.ToFullString();
            return result;
        }
    }

    public class Field
    {
        public string FieldName;
        public string FieldType;

        public Field(string fieldName, string fieldType)
        {
            FieldName = fieldName;
            FieldType = fieldType;
        }
    }

    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static string ToString(this IEnumerable<string> list, string separator)
        {
            string result = string.Join(separator, list);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You want to look at [CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx?assembly). It allows defining code elements and compiling them. Quoting MSDN:

> ...This object graph can be rendered as
>   source code using a CodeDOM code
>   generator for a supported programming
>   language. The CodeDOM can also be used
>   to compile source code into a binary
>   assembly.

Comment: I want this to be generated in runtime. I dont want a physical CS file residing in my filesystem. Sorry for not mentioning that earlier.

Comment: @ashwnacharya: You **can** use CodeDOM for both generating the source file and compiling it at runtime!

Comment: Beware though, that the CodeDOM compiler takes a raw string, and thus you might want to consider "code insertion attacks" similar to those used in XSS and SQL injection.

Answer (score 10):

You can also dynamically create a class by using [DynamicExpressions](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions).

Since 'Dictionary's have compact initializers and handle key collisions, you will want to do something like this.

```
  var list = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    {
      "EmployeeID",
      "int"
    }, {
      "EmployeeName",
      "String"
    }, {
      "Birthday",
      "DateTime"
    }
  };
```

Or you might want to use a JSON converter to construct your serialized string object into something manageable.

Then using System.Linq.Dynamic;

```
  IEnumerable<DynamicProperty> props = list.Select(property => new DynamicProperty(property.Key, Type.GetType(property.Value))).ToList();

  Type t = DynamicExpression.CreateClass(props);
```

The rest is just using System.Reflection.

```
  object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
  t.GetProperty("EmployeeID").SetValue(obj, 34, null);
  t.GetProperty("EmployeeName").SetValue(obj, "Albert", null);
  t.GetProperty("Birthday").SetValue(obj, new DateTime(1976, 3, 14), null);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Based on @danijels's answer, dynamically create a class in VB.NET:

```
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Reflection.Emit

Public Class ObjectBuilder

Public Property myType As Object
Public Property myObject As Object

Public Sub New(fields As List(Of Field))
    myType = CompileResultType(fields)
    myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(myType)
End Sub

Public Shared Function CompileResultType(fields As List(Of Field)) As Type
    Dim tb As TypeBuilder = GetTypeBuilder()
    Dim constructor As ConstructorBuilder = tb.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.[Public] Or MethodAttributes.SpecialName Or MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName)

    For Each field In fields
        CreateProperty(tb, field.Name, field.Type)
    Next

    Dim objectType As Type = tb.CreateType()
    Return objectType
End Function

Private Shared Function GetTypeBuilder() As TypeBuilder
    Dim typeSignature = "MyDynamicType"
    Dim an = New AssemblyName(typeSignature)
    Dim assemblyBuilder As AssemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(an, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run)
    Dim moduleBuilder As ModuleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MainModule")
    Dim tb As TypeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType(typeSignature, TypeAttributes.[Public] Or TypeAttributes.[Class] Or TypeAttributes.AutoClass Or TypeAttributes.AnsiClass Or TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit Or TypeAttributes.AutoLayout, Nothing)
    Return tb
End Function

Private Shared Sub CreateProperty(tb As TypeBuilder, propertyName As String, propertyType As Type)
    Dim fieldBuilder As FieldBuilder = tb.DefineField("_" & propertyName, propertyType, FieldAttributes.[Private])

    Dim propertyBuilder As PropertyBuilder = tb.DefineProperty(propertyName, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, propertyType, Nothing)
    Dim getPropMthdBldr As MethodBuilder = tb.DefineMethod("get_" & propertyName, MethodAttributes.[Public] Or MethodAttributes.SpecialName Or MethodAttributes.HideBySig, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes)
    Dim getIl As ILGenerator = getPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator()

    getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0)
    getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder)
    getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret)

    Dim setPropMthdBldr As MethodBuilder = tb.DefineMethod("set_" & propertyName, MethodAttributes.[Public] Or MethodAttributes.SpecialName Or MethodAttributes.HideBySig, Nothing, {propertyType})

    Dim setIl As ILGenerator = setPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator()
    Dim modifyProperty As Label = setIl.DefineLabel()
    Dim exitSet As Label = setIl.DefineLabel()

    setIl.MarkLabel(modifyProperty)
    setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0)
    setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1)
    setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder)

    setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Nop)
    setIl.MarkLabel(exitSet)
    setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret)

    propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getPropMthdBldr)
    propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setPropMthdBldr)
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 8):

For those wanting to create a dynamic class just properties (i.e. POCO), and create a list of this class.  Using the code provided later, this will create a dynamic class and create a list of this.

```
var properties = new List<DynamicTypeProperty>()
{
    new DynamicTypeProperty("doubleProperty", typeof(double)),
    new DynamicTypeProperty("stringProperty", typeof(string))
};

// create the new type
var dynamicType = DynamicType.CreateDynamicType(properties);
// create a list of the new type
var dynamicList = DynamicType.CreateDynamicList(dynamicType);

// get an action that will add to the list
var addAction = DynamicType.GetAddAction(dynamicList);

// call the action, with an object[] containing parameters in exact order added
addAction.Invoke(new object[] {1.1, "item1"});
addAction.Invoke(new object[] {2.1, "item2"});
addAction.Invoke(new object[] {3.1, "item3"});
```

Here are the classes that the previous code uses.

Note: You'll also need to reference the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp library.

```
       /// <summary>
    /// A property name, and type used to generate a property in the dynamic class.
    /// </summary>
    public class DynamicTypeProperty
    {
        public DynamicTypeProperty(string name, Type type)
        {
            Name = name;
            Type = type;
        }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Type Type { get; set; }
    }

   public static class DynamicType
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a list of the specified type
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="type"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IEnumerable<object> CreateDynamicList(Type type)
        {
            var listType = typeof(List<>);
            var dynamicListType = listType.MakeGenericType(type);
            return (IEnumerable<object>) Activator.CreateInstance(dynamicListType);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// creates an action which can be used to add items to the list
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="listType"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Action<object[]> GetAddAction(IEnumerable<object> list)
        {
            var listType = list.GetType();
            var addMethod = listType.GetMethod("Add");
            var itemType = listType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
            var itemProperties = itemType.GetProperties();

            var action = new Action<object[]>((values) =>
            {
                var item = Activator.CreateInstance(itemType);

                for(var i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    itemProperties[i].SetValue(item, values[i]);
                }

                addMethod.Invoke(list, new []{item});
            });

            return action;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a type based on the property/type values specified in the properties
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="properties"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        /// <exception cref="Exception"></exception>
        public static Type CreateDynamicType(IEnumerable<DynamicTypeProperty> properties)
        {
            StringBuilder classCode = new StringBuilder();

            // Generate the class code
            classCode.AppendLine("using System;");
            classCode.AppendLine("namespace Dexih {");
            classCode.AppendLine("public class DynamicClass {");

            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                classCode.AppendLine($"public {property.Type.Name} {property.Name} {{get; set; }}");
            }
            classCode.AppendLine("}");
            classCode.AppendLine("}");

            var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(classCode.ToString());

            var references = new MetadataReference[]
            {
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(DictionaryBase).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location)
            };

            var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("DynamicClass" + Guid.NewGuid() + ".dll",
                syntaxTrees: new[] {syntaxTree},
                references: references,
                options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary));

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var result = compilation.Emit(ms);

                if (!result.Success)
                {
                    var failures = result.Diagnostics.Where(diagnostic =>
                        diagnostic.IsWarningAsError ||
                        diagnostic.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Error);

                    var message = new StringBuilder();

                    foreach (var diagnostic in failures)
                    {
                        message.AppendFormat("{0}: {1}", diagnostic.Id, diagnostic.GetMessage());
                    }

                    throw new Exception($"Invalid property definition: {message}.");
                }
                else
                {

                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    var assembly = System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromStream(ms);
                    var dynamicType = assembly.GetType("Dexih.DynamicClass");
                    return dynamicType;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Great piece of code. Would be possible to use also AddRange on the dynamic list, to eventually add several records at a time?

Answer (score 3):

You can look at using dynamic modules and classes that can do the job. The only disadvantage is that it remains loaded in the app domain. But with the version of .NET framework being used, that could change. .NET 4.0 supports collectible dynamic assemblies and hence you can recreate the classes/types dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

Wow! Thank you for that answer! I added some features to it to create a "datatable to json" converter that I share with you.

```
    Public Shared Sub dt2json(ByVal _dt As DataTable, ByVal _sb As StringBuilder)
    Dim t As System.Type

    Dim oList(_dt.Rows.Count - 1) As Object
    Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    t = CompileResultType(_dt)

    For Each dr As DataRow In _dt.Rows
        Dim o As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(t)

        For Each col As DataColumn In _dt.Columns
            setvalue(o, col.ColumnName, dr.Item(col.ColumnName))
        Next

        oList(i) = o
        i += 1
    Next

    jss = New JavaScriptSerializer()
    jss.Serialize(oList, _sb)


End Sub
```

And in "compileresulttype" sub, I changed that:

```
    For Each column As DataColumn In _dt.Columns
        CreateProperty(tb, column.ColumnName, column.DataType)
    Next


Private Shared Sub setvalue(ByVal _obj As Object, ByVal _propName As String, ByVal _propValue As Object)
    Dim pi As PropertyInfo
    pi = _obj.GetType.GetProperty(_propName)
    If pi IsNot Nothing AndAlso pi.CanWrite Then
        If _propValue IsNot DBNull.Value Then
            pi.SetValue(_obj, _propValue, Nothing)

        Else
            Select Case pi.PropertyType.ToString
                Case "System.String"
                    pi.SetValue(_obj, String.Empty, Nothing)
                Case Else
                    'let the serialiser use javascript "null" value.
            End Select

        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use CSharpProvider:

```
var code = @"
    public class Abc {
       public string Get() { return ""abc""; }
    }
";

var options = new CompilerParameters();
options.GenerateExecutable = false;
options.GenerateInMemory = false;

var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
var compile = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(options, code);

var type = compile.CompiledAssembly.GetType("Abc");
var abc = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

var method = type.GetMethod("Get");
var result = method.Invoke(abc, null);

Console.WriteLine(result); //output: abc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.  It will allow you to use "normal" code rather than low level assembly type stuff.

See the RealProxy answer to this question for a good example:

[How do I intercept a method call in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803/how-do-i-intercept-a-method-call-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 questions here:

##### 1. I want to create a class that looks like this: Is there any way to do this ?

```cs
class DynamicClass
{
    int EmployeeID,
    String EmployeeName,
    String Designation
}
```

Yes, this is possible but the purpose should not be to make a class look like something but to work, behave and hold the data like this. And this is achievable whiteout using `CodeGeneration`, "`T4 Template`, `dynamic`, `ExpandoObject`, `CSharpProvider` or `AnonymousObject`.

---

##### 2. I want this to be generated at runtime.

Generating a `class` at runtime won't do anything if it doesn't create a `instance` object.

And if I understand you are trying to save `Employee` data where the size of `List<Field>` is unbound and the best you can think of is to generate a `class`  to hold that unbounded data dynamically at runtime.

---

##### Creating DynamicEntity

If that is your issue you can attempt to create `Employee` as a `Entity` like below called as `DynamicEntity` where the properties are available as a `Dictionary<string,object>` so it can be extended with new attributes/fields without the need of a new `class` design and it's not limited to 2-3 fields for employee.

```cs
public class DynamicEntity
{
    public string Name {get;private set;}
    public Dictionary<string,object> Attributes;
    
    public DynamicEntity(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Attributes = new Dictionary<string,object>();
        Attributes.Add("LogicalName",name);
        Attributes.Add("Id",Guid.NewGuid());
    }
    
    public object this[string key]
    {
        get {
            return Attributes[key];
        }
        
        set{
            Attributes[key] = value;
        }
    }
    
    public void AddAttribute<T>(string attributeName,T data)
    {
        Attributes.Add(attributeName,data);
    }
    
    public void SetAttributeValue<T>(string attributeName,T data)
    {
        Attributes[attributeName] = data;
    }
    
    public T GetAttributeValue<T>(string attributeName)
    {
        return (T)Attributes[attributeName];
    }
}
```

To use you can create an object at runtime and read/write/append attributes to it.

```cs
    var u = new DynamicEntity("employee"); //new object
    
    u.AddAttribute<int>("EmployeeID",10); //Add Id
    u["EmployeeName"]= "vinod"; //Add Name
    u["Designation"] = "hacker"; //Add Designation
    
    u.AddAttribute<string>("Address","India"); //Add New Attribute 
    
    u.SetAttributeValue<string>("EmployeeName","Vinod Srivastav");
    
    var id = u.GetAttributeValue<int>("EmployeeID"); //Read Attribute
```

If everything goes well you can get a object like follows:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[`Runtime Code Generation with JVM and CLR`](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/326a/0e09be808978c3bb9fdd006f3041dc0cbc13.pdf) - 
Peter Sestoft

Work for persons that are really interested in this type of programming.

My tip for You is that if You declare something try to avoid string, so if You have class Field it is better to use class [System.Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) to store the field type than a string. 
And for the sake of best solutions instead of creation new classes try to use those that has been created [FiledInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.aspx) instead of creation new.

Comment: Link is dead: -1

Comment: Glenn: a quick googling revealed a working link: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/326a/0e09be808978c3bb9fdd006f3041dc0cbc13.pdf

Comment: @AndreasPardeike Thanks, I repaired it in the article.