# Is it possible to create a new type on fly (add properties depending on the type of data )?

Tags: c#

my application read Excel sheets and display it as a table. What I do is reading DataTable and putting data in an object of type:

```
List<List<string>>
```

To display data on the page I use 2 loops (inner and outer) to recreate the table.

What I'd like to do is to create a new type **MyType**, for instance. Then add properties to it depending in number and value types to the headers of the Excel data. I believe it's easier to work with type.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Related but not the same: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3862226/121309

Comment: @Hans Kesting: Yes, that is more or less whatI want. But, it's just heavy with the code.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be looking for [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx), which lets you add arbitrary properties to each object at run-time. For example:

```
dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();      // initially empty object
obj.Spread = "Nutella";   // obj now has a “Spread” property of type string
```

Of course, you can then put this object into a `List<dynamic>` along with all the other objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using reflection.
take a look at the [TypeBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.aspx) class

Answer (score 0):

Maybe anonymous types?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx

You *do* need to set the properties all in one go, though.

Comment: I think that the properties are only known at run-time.