# telerik grid bnding with dynamic columns

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

I'm using telerik MVC grid and my columns are dynamic for grid, means I can't bind the grid with strongly type model.

Through Ajax call, somehow I get the data in below image format (there are 3 column)

now question, how can i bind these records to grid, currently below code display nothing.

```
 @model IEnumerable<dynamic>
 @(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
                .Name("grdHierarchy")
                .Sortable()
                .Pageable()
                .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Enabled(true)))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using the auto-generated columns concept presented [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/autogeneratecolumns)? Might be plausible for scenario like yours.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
.Columns(columns => columns.LoadSettings(Model.Columns))
```

Where Model.Columns are defined this way:

```
public List<GridColumnSettings> Columns { get; set; }
```

See this demo: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/columnsettings

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but try this:

```
 .Columns(col => {                           
                   col.Bound("DynamicColumnName");
                 })
```

Just pass the column name as strings.

Answer (score 0):

For a truly dynamic experience, i.e. you have no idea what the class will be and no idea what the properties will be until run time, you can combine these two concepts.

[How to dynamically create a class in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862226/dynamically-create-a-class-in-c-sharp)

with

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/Grid/ColumnSettings