# C# - How to check if namespace, class or method exists in C#?

Tags: c#, class, methods, namespaces

I have a C# program, how can I check at runtime if a namespace, class, or method exists? Also, how to instantiate a class by using it's name in the form of string?

Pseudocode:

```
string @namespace = "MyNameSpace";
string @class = "MyClass";
string method= "MyMEthod";

var y = IsNamespaceExists(namespace);
var x = IsClassExists(@class)? new @class : null; //Check if exists, instantiate if so.
var z = x.IsMethodExists(method);
```

Comment: Please remember to mark the most appropriate response as an answer.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use [Type.GetType(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) to [reflect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) a type. `GetType` will return null if the type could not be found. If the type exists, you can then use `GetMethod`, `GetField`, `GetProperty`, etc. from the returned `Type` to check if the member you're interested in exists.

[Update](https://dotnetfiddle.net/T5dDtM) to your example:

```
string @namespace = "MyNameSpace";
string @class = "MyClass";
string method= "MyMEthod";

var myClassType = Type.GetType(String.format("{0}.{1}", @namespace, @class));
object instance = myClassType == null ? null : Activator.CreateInstance(myClassType); //Check if exists, instantiate if so.
var myMethodExists = myClassType.GetMethod(method) != null;

Console.WriteLine(myClassType); // MyNameSpace.MyClass
Console.WriteLine(myMethodExists); // True
```

This is the most efficient and preferred method, assuming the type is in the **currently executing assembly**, in mscorlib (not sure how .NET Core affects this, perhaps `System.Runtime` instead?), or you have an [assembly-qualified name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname?view=netframework-4.8#System_Type_AssemblyQualifiedName) for the type. If the string argument you pass to `GetType` does not satisfy those three requirements, `GetType` will return null (assuming there isn't some other type that accidentally does overlap those requirements, oops).

---

If you **don't** have the assembly qualified name, you'll either need to fix your approach so you do or perform a search, the latter being potentially much slower.

If we assume you do want to search for the type in all loaded assemblies, you can do something like this (using LINQ):

```
var type = (from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            from type in assembly.GetTypes()
            where type.Name == className
            select type);
```

Of course, there may be more to it than that, where you'll want to reflect over referenced assemblies that may not be loaded yet, etc.

As for determining the namespaces, reflection doesn't export those distinctly. Instead, you'd have to do something like:

```
var namespaceFound = (from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
from type in assembly.GetTypes()
where type.Namespace == namespace
select type).Any()
```

Putting it all together, you'd have something like:

```
var type = (from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                from type in assembly.GetTypes()
                where type.Name == className && type.GetMethods().Any(m => m.Name == methodName)
                select type).FirstOrDefault();

if (type == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Valid type not found.");

object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Comment: And how would you determine if a namespace exists with your examples?

Comment: Updated my answer. Check the second code example. We enumerate each loaded assembly, and each type in each assembly, and look for any type that has desired namespace name.

Comment: If you want to check that the namespace is valid, the class name is valid, and the class has a method, you can do that all in one shot with the third code example. just change where type.Name == className to something like `where type.FullName == string.Format("{0}.{1}", namespace, className) && type.GetMethods().Any(m => m.Name == methodName)`. Also, I made a mistake in those examples by leaving out the `select` part of the statement. corrected.

Comment: +1 Nice example. I hadn't even realized that there was a Type.Namespace property...

Comment: You could do this with nested `foreach` loops; i just went with LINQ because it's easier. I can provide such an example if you'd prefer.

Answer (score 40):

You can resolve a [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) from a string by using the [Type.GetType(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) method.
For example:

```
Type myType = Type.GetType("MyNamespace.MyClass");
```

You can then use this Type instance to check if a method exists on the type by calling the [GetMethod(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zz808e6.aspx) method. 
For example:

```
MethodInfo myMethod = myType.GetMethod("MyMethod");
```

Both GetType and GetMethod return `null` if no type or method was found for the given name, so you can check if your type/method exist by checking if your method call returned null or not.

Finally, you can instantiate your type using [Activator.CreateInstance(Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx)
For example:

```
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
```

Comment: This is a much quicker and more concise answer than the one marked as correct above. Spinning every type in every assembly is painfully slow. If you include all the System assemblies, that might be a 10,000 iteration loop.

Comment: This is what I was after, short and simple.

Answer (score 2):

One word: [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection). Except for Namespaces, you'll have to parse those out of the Type names.

**EDIT:** Strike that - for namespaces you'll have to use the Type.Namespace property to determine which namespace each class belongs to. (See [HackedByChinese response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8499606/635634) for more information).

Comment: Reflection URL is down unfortunately

Comment: Fixed broken reflection link.