# Reflection and checking for existance of method

Tags: c#, reflection

I have two variables, `ns` and `method` storing the namespace and a method name for working with an api. I have an api library, where once you have an instance, you access the methods as `api.namespace.method()`

How do I go about checking for the existance of `namespace` and `method` with the api object from the variables? At the moment I'm switching over the variables but of course, this doesn't scale too well!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - How to check if namespace, class or method exists in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499593/c-sharp-how-to-check-if-namespace-class-or-method-exists-in-c)

Comment: Method should be inside a type in c#. You can't have method directly in namespace.