# C# .Net PDF reader

Tags: c#, pdf, adobe

I need to add Pdf reader element in programm C# WinForms for display PDF-file.
I tried to use Pdfium SDK, but it's commercial library.
Just I tried using Adobe Active X Library. But for run this application wants to installed Adobe Reader.
If Adobe Reader is not installed, need to run AdobeReaderSetup.exe.
How can I check Adobe Reader installed?

Comment: Have you checked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39198669/check-if-adobe-reader-is-installed-before-using-it

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of installed applications by iterating over the Registry key `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`.

```
using(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"))
{
    foreach(string skn in key.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
        using(RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(skn))
        {
            if(subkey.GetValue("DisplayName").Contains("Adobe PDF")) {
               // Process accordingly
            }
        }
    }
}
```