# PowerShell - Check if .NET class exists

Tags: .net, powershell, types

I have a DLL file that I am importing into the PS session.  This creates a new .NET class.  At the start of the function I want to test if this class exists, and if it doesn't import the DLL file.

Currently I am trying to call the class.  This works but I think it's causing problems with the Do {} Until () loop since I have to run the script twice.

my code.  note the `Do {} Until ()` loop isn't working.
https://gist.github.com/TheRealNoob/f07e0d981a3e079db13d16fe00116a9a

I have found the `[System.Type]::GetType()` Method but when I run it against any kind of string, valid or invalid class, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Are you able to see the methods and properties for that custom class? 
`[classname]::Method` .. Have you tried to access like this ?

Comment: Yes I can test methods that way.  But is that really the best way?  Surely there has to be real solutions to this.

Comment: Yes, there is no harm in that. Its the dot net approach. YOu can store the result in a variable and use it wherever you wish

Comment: See also: [“How do I conditionally add a class with Add-Type -TypeDefinition if it isn't added already?”](/q/16552801).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .Net it exists something called Reflexion which allow you deal with everything in your code.

```
$type = [System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | % { $_.GetTypes() | where {$_.Name -eq 'String'}}
```

Here I look for the type `String`, but you can look for your type or better the version of the Assembly, you can even find if one method exists with the correct arguments. Have a look to [C# - How to check if namespace, class or method exists in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8499593/608772).

---

@Timmerman comments ; he went with :

```
[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | % { $_.GetTypes() | where {$_.Name -like "SQLiteConnection"}}
```

or

```
[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | % { $_.GetTypes() | where {$_.AssemblyQualifiedName -like 'Assembly Qualified Name'}}
```

Comment: I have read that article.  But I don't think you quite understand what I am looking to do.  My DLL file creates (following your example) [System.AppDomain].  I need to know if that exists or not.  I can't just write If ( (!( [System.AppDomain] -as [type])) ) { #do stuff } because that results in a terminating error.

Comment: I think JAPBlanc, he is trying to externally load that and call that explicitly.

Comment: Ranadip Dutta, that is correct.  you can test my predicament with any fake class.  example:
If ( (!( [System.NewClass] -as [type])) ) { Add-Type MyDLL.dll }

Comment: You don't understand.  PowerShell is a .NET EXE with an AppDomain. Add-type add an assembly to this AppDomain. This code just test if your class exists in the current PowerShell instance.

Comment: JPBlanc, you are correct.  Your solution works perfectly and then some :)  To all future readers the command I am going with is as follows:  **[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | % { $_.GetTypes() | where {$_.Name -like "SQLiteConnection"}}** OR  **[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | % { $_.GetTypes() | where {$_.AssemblyQualifiedName -like 'Assembly Qualified Name'}}**

Answer (score 10):

You can cast a string to a `[system.type]` in powershell using [`-as`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_type_operators):

```
PS C:\> 'int' -as [type]

IsPublic IsSerial Name    BaseType
-------- -------- ----    --------
True     True     Int32   System.ValueType
```

If the type cannot be found (as with other cast scenarios) then nothing is returned from the expression:

```
PS C:\> 'notatype' -as [type]

PS C:\>
```

Thus you can retrieve a specific type (without iterating through all types of all assemblies loaded in the app domain) with:

```
$type = 'notatype' -as [type]

#or

if ('int' -as [type]) { 
  'Success!' 
}

#and conveniently

$typeName = 'Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection'
if (-not($typeName -as [type])) {
   #load the type
}
```

Comment: h/t [SeeminglyScience's](https://www.reddit.com/user/SeeminglyScience/) response to [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/7ak39n/how_to_use_systemtypegettype/dpapjb0/)

Answer (score 2):

This is what -is and -as were made for.  You can also use -is with a try/catch statement to check if the class is there:

```
try
{
   [test.namespace] -is [type]
}
catch
{
    add-type -typedefinition test.namespace.dll
}
```

el2iot2 perfectly describes the use of the -as and would be my preferred approach.  It is intended to not through errors during class conversion.

Answer (score 0):

**I recommend [the el2iot2's approach with `-as`](/a/57628696)**.

**If you like the try-catch way more than `-as`, I recommend you to replace `[SomeType]::Equals($null, $null)` in my answer with `[SomeType] -is [type]`, per [the Shaun Stevens's answer](/a/62306531)**.

But, if I had read neither el2iot2's nor Shaun Stevens's answer, I would use the following:

```
try {
    [SomeType]::Equals($null, $null) >$null
    Write-Host '"SomeType" exists'
}
catch {
    Write-Host '"SomeType" does not exist'
}
```

(Explanation: every type should have the `Equals` static method, which allows to call itself with two `$null`s and returns `$true` in such case; trying to refer a non-existing type in this way should throw an instance of `SystemException`, which can be caught.)

It can be even used as one-liner:

```
$someTypeExists = try {[SomeType]::Equals($null, $null)} catch {$false}
```