# Dynamically creation of C# Class

Tags: c#, .net

How to dynamically create a C# Class. I have 3 method informations. I have to create a dynamic C# class and it should consist of those 3 methods. Any ideas?..

Answer (score 3):

if saying `class`, you need just to have a `type` with this 3 methods, you can use [DynamicObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx).

This is special type of objects in `C#`, that permits *runtime*  add/remove of members to an instance of that type.

Comment: Can u please give me some exaples?

Comment: @senthilkumar Here's an example of how to use DynamicObject:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461504.aspx

Comment: Can u please explain with some example. Like, my dynamic class name (Type) should be Test and the method details are.. Method 1: public int add(int a, int b) {....} Method 2: public void display(string str){....} Method 3 public string SayHello(string name){....}

Comment: @senthilkumar: that was actually a point in my asnwer. If you need some precise type, so *named* type, you should follow the link of the answer that was deleted (don't know why) were you create a *new type*. Here is it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862226/dynamically-create-a-class-in-c-sharp