# Why I cannot create a List<> using myObject?

Tags: c#

I created a class dynamically (found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862226/dynamically-create-a-class-in-c-sharp)) but I don't understand why I cannot use it to create a list?

```
var myType = CompileResultType();
var myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
var myList = new List<myObject>();

// Error: The type or namespace name 'myObject' 
// could not be found (are you missing a using directive 
// or an assembly reference?)
```

How should I do it?

Comment: They're called generic *type* parameters, because they expect types, not instances. So you need to know the actual type or create the list object with reflection as well. =)

Comment: @J.Steen You should add it as an answer `;)`

Comment: would you be so kind as well to correct my snippet? : )

Comment: May be this [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1644998.aspx/1) can help you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're called generic type parameters, because they expect types, not instances. So you need to know the actual type or create the list object with reflection as well.

```
Type listType = typeof(List<>);
Type dynamicClassType = listType.MakeGenericType(myObject.GetType());
object myList = Activator.CreateInstance(dynamicClassType);
```

However, you're unable to *use* the instance in any meaningful way since it's an object.

- You could cast it to an `IList` as suggested in [Avner Shahar-Kashtan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17802689/64976) and use the nongeneric methods.

  ```
  IList myList = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(dynamicClassType);
  ```
- You could call the methods of the list-instance through reflection as well.

  ```
  // roughly
  MethodInfo addMethod = myList.GetType().GetMethod("Add");
  addMethod.Invoke(myList, objectToAdd);
  ```
- Or do as suggested in [Cuong Le's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17802684/64976) and use `dynamic` as the type of the list-instance.

  ```
  dynamic myList = Activator.CreateInstance(dynamicClassType);
  ```

Answer (score 6):

In order to construct a generic type dynamically, you'll have to use Reflection, and specifically the [MakeGenericType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx) method. Something like this:

```
Type baseListType = typeof(List<>); // get the generic List<>
Type myType = CompileResultType; // same as in yours.
Type myListType = baseListType.MakeGenericType(myType); // Get the List<MyType>
IList myList = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(myListType); // Instantiate.
```

Notice that I defined `myList` as `IList`, since we don't have a compile-time type for it. Luckily, we have convenient base classes and interfaces like `IList`, `IEnumerable` and several others that `List<T>` implements, which we can use.

Answer (score 2):

Generic type need a type of class, not instance, maybe you need:

```
var myType = CompileResultType();
var listType = typeof (List<>).MakeGenericType(myType);
var myList = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
```

But `myList` in here is `object`, if you would like to add or remove item in list, you should take advantage of `dynamic`:

```
dynamic myList = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
```

So you can call:

```
myList.Add(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

this will create type of list `List<WhatEverIsInMyType>`:

```
var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(myType);
```

now you need to create an instance but that you have covered:

```
var list = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
```

Unfortunately we are using reflection so exact types are not known at compile time but not all is lost you can use nongeneric types:

```
    var list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
```

now you can use methods like `Add` `Remove` to use your list but be careful because you will get runtime exceptions if types don't math.

Answer (score 0):

You work with *types*, not *instances*. Assuming `CompileResultType()` returns `MyType`:

```cs
MyType myType = CompileResultType();
List<MyType> list = new List<MyType>();
```

I'm not sure why you're using `Activator.CreateInstance()` though ...