# How to bind a model to a dynamically created class nancyfx

Tags: c#, json, nancy

first of all thanks for anyone who's willing to have a look at my problem. I'm pretty new with Nancyfx and I'm having issues with trying to bind a JSON payload to a dynamically created class.
I created the class dynamically by following the code in this post - [Dynamically create a class in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862226/dynamically-create-a-class-in-c-sharp)

This is my block of code that creates the dynamic class, which I admit is essentially a cut and paste of the code given by [danijels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21692/danijels)

```
 public static Type CompileResultType(List<Metadata> metadata)
    {            
        TypeBuilder tb = GetTypeBuilder();
        ConstructorBuilder constructor = tb.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName);

        foreach (var field in metadata)
        {
            if(field.datatype == "String")
            {
               Type datatype = Type.GetType("System.String");
               CreateProperty(tb, field.columnname, datatype);
            }
            if (field.datatype == "int")
            {
                Type datatype = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
                CreateProperty(tb, field.columnname, datatype);
            }
            if(field.datatype == "datetime")
            {
                Type datatype = Type.GetType("System.DateTime");
                CreateProperty(tb, field.columnname, datatype);
            }

        }

        Type objectType = tb.CreateType();

        return objectType;

    }


    private static TypeBuilder GetTypeBuilder()
    {
        var typeSignature = "MyDynamicType";
        var an = new AssemblyName(typeSignature);
        AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(an, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MainModule");

        TypeBuilder tb;

        tb = moduleBuilder.DefineType(typeSignature, TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.AutoClass | TypeAttributes.AnsiClass | TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit | TypeAttributes.AutoLayout, null);

        return tb;

    }

    private static void CreateProperty(TypeBuilder tb, string propertyName, Type propertyType)
    {
        FieldBuilder fieldBuilder = tb.DefineField(propertyName, propertyType, FieldAttributes.Public); //changed field attributes from private to public

        PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = tb.DefineProperty(propertyName, System.Reflection.PropertyAttributes.None, propertyType, null);

        MethodBuilder getPropMethdBldr = tb.DefineMethod("get_" + propertyName, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes); //changed get_ to get

        ILGenerator getIl = getPropMethdBldr.GetILGenerator();

        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        MethodBuilder setPropMthdBldr = tb.DefineMethod("set_" + propertyName, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, null, new[] { propertyType }); //changed set_to set

        ILGenerator setIl = setPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
        Label modifyProperty = setIl.DefineLabel();
        Label exitSet = setIl.DefineLabel();

        setIl.MarkLabel(modifyProperty);
        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);

        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
        setIl.MarkLabel(exitSet);
        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getPropMethdBldr);
        propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(setPropMthdBldr);
    }

//List<Metadata> metadata is a Dictionary
```

I then bind it by doing this

```
  var myType = CompileResultType(metadata);
  var myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
  var b = this.BindTo(myObject);
```

I can't have a normal model class for Nancy because I will have too many models just for harvesting the data.

```
//usual model class
public Class PayloadModel
{
   public string firstName {get; set;}
   public string lastName {get; set;}
}
```

The reason I have to create the class dynamically is because the JSON payload that I receive varies from having 1 field to having 30. Another reason is that I'd like to keep it as flexible as possible. and by having the above class means that I'm tied down to whatever is in that class. Any advice or direction will be of great help!

Comment: what is not working in the code you have? E.g. does this.BindTo throw an exception or ??

Comment: Sorry probably should've stated what's happening. Its not binding to the dynamic class. Its not so much that it throws an exception, its just that the values in the model class is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you may be better off using a Dynamic type:

https://gist.github.com/thecodejunkie/5521941

TheCodeJunkie has a custom model binder for Dynamic. You should be able to use this to do:

`dynamic model = this.Bind<DynamicDictionary>();`

Comment: Will I be able to access the incoming json payload through that?

Comment: @norm15 if you use 'dynamic' then you can access any property like `model.UserId` or `model["UserId"]` - it wont work if you use `var` though you can use `["UserId"]` on var since its a dictionary.

Comment: Yes I have used dynamic model = this.Bind<DynamicDictionary>() and it works great  that I have a "model" class that won't change. My issue is that I can't have a "model" class due to the business requirements so I programatically made a "model" class in run-time. I then try to bind the json packet to that model but it comes up with null values. Sorry if it seems so messy and round about.

Comment: @norm15 I'm not sure I understand. Using dynamic you can serialize/deserialize to JSON. And get all data that was passed in. No need to create a proxy object.

Comment: @Phill Does this work with nested deep models ? (Ie. json with deeped hierarchy passed as a parameter)