# How to add custom control at Run time in c#

Tags: c#, windows

i have one list box which has button, Textbox, Label. During runtime i will drag and drop the item from the list box, according to the selection the dynamic control will be created. (For example, If i select and drag Button from list box and drop it on the Windows Form, the button will be created). As same as i have created a CustomControl for Button. how can i add it in my list box at runtime? i mean while i drag and drop the button from the listbox the custom button should be generated.  How to Do it?

Comment: Are you saying you have the code to drag/drop, but it is not working for your own custom control classes?

Comment: I am clearly saying that i have a custom control which is a button, i want to load it to list box. and also i want to drag and drop to winform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For drag drop, you will need to set up 3 events:

1. A mouse down event on the list box to trigger the dragging:

   ```
   private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       listBox1.DoDragDrop(listBox1.SelectedItem, DragDropEffects.Copy);
   }
   ```
2. A drag enter event on your form (or panel in this example):

   ```
   private void panel1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
       {
           e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
       }
   }
   ```
3. And finally the drop event on the form/panel:

   ```
   private void panel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
   {
       Control newControl = null;
       // you would really use a better design pattern to do this, but
       // for demo purposes I'm using a switch statement
       string selectedItem = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text) as string;
       switch (selectedItem)
       {
           case "My Custom Control":
               newControl = new CustomControl();
               newControl.Location = panel1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
               newControl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
               break;
       }

       if (newControl != null) panel1.Controls.Add(newControl);
   }
   ```

For this to work you must set "AllowDrop" to true on the target form/panel.

Use @Marty's answer to add the custom control to the listbox. Override the `ToString()` for a better description. There are so many ways of doing it. The important part is deciding what data type the list items will be and making sure that the correct type name is used in the `e.Data.GetDataPresent` method. `e.Data.GetFormats()` can help determine what name to use.

Answer (score 1):

Did You try this ?

```
var list = new ListBox();
list.Controls.Add(new Button());
```

If You need to dynamically create a class at runtime - take a look at this SF article [How to dynamically create a class in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862226/dynamically-create-a-class-in-c-sharp)

Comment: this is dynamic control. i did it successfully. What i want is custom control.

Comment: What do You mean by dynamic control ? why cant you do list.Controls.Add(new MyCustomButton()); ?