# Modify property retrieved at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, runtime

I have a class that I'd like to be generic in that I can specify the property to retrieve from the object at runtime.  The reason for this is that we have a database table accessed via Entity Framework that has many columns such as,

1. table.name1
2. table.name2
3. table.name3
   .
   .
   .

Terrible legacy table notwithstanding, I'd like to do something similar to the following while allowing for either indexing or straight-out specifying the object property.

```
public string Name
{ 
    get { return name<#>; } 
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: So, you know that you need to use reflection. What is the real problem?

Comment: I'm struggling with how to best specify the index efficiently at runtime.  Instantiate the class with an index parameter?  That seems ugly.

Comment: Why index? Can't you pass the property name? Using reflection, you can get the list of all properties of the class (names) and get or set properties using the property name

Comment: here is an example: http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-property-names/

Comment: Also, look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks.  I'm just trying to avoid the hardcoding of the property name because there are many that have a similar naming convention in our database.

Comment: Are you trying to create the class dynamically at runtime? If so, look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862226/how-to-dynamically-create-a-class-in-c

Comment: Yes, essentially.  It's difficult to represent the complexity with an example but basically there are multiple tables involved so the top-level class uses generics to determine the data object.  Therefore I was considering passing in an index along with the generic type.