# C# Build anonymous object dynamically

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, anonymous-types, reflection.emit

In C# I can easily create an anonymous object like this at the compile time:

```
var items = new {
 Price = 2000,
 Description = "",
 Locations = new List<string> { "", "" }  
};
```

My question is, it's possible to create this object at the runtime ?
I've heard of **emit/meta programming**, but I don't know if it helps here.

Noting that these objects will be created inside a for loop (100 items or more), so I recommend techniques that allow type caching.

Thanks.

## Update - Why I need this

- One example could be implementing the `Include` functionality like in `db.Users.Include("Users")`, so I need to add the `Users` property at runtime on demand.

Comment: can you post the code for `for` loop just to see what you are trying

Comment: What is the purpose of such dynamically typed types?

Answer (score 2):

Anonymous types are generated on compile time, and are just regular types.

Since you are talking beyond the compilation process, you don't have the 'generate an (anonymous) type on compile time' option any more, unless you compile the type yourself to an assembly you load right after generating it. [System.Reflection.Emit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3862241/993547) is your friend here. This is quite expensive though.

Personally I would skip all that hassle, and look into a type that is dynamic by nature, like `ExpandoObject`. You can add properties, just like you would add entries to a dictionary:

```
dynamic eo = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
IDictionary<string, object> d = (IDictionary<string, object>)eo;
d["a"] = "b";

string a = eo.a;
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, isn't expando objects  two slow in this case ?

Comment: It is basically a dictionary. That can't be really that slow.