# Convert JSON file into C# Classes dynamically and write it to a file during run time

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, class

I have a requirement to convert a JSON file into C# Class and to create a C# Class at a specific folder in the system.

For ex:

> {    "id": "string",    "fullName": "string" }

This JSON can change during run time.I need to convert this into C# Class like

```
 public class Root    {
    public string id { get; set; } 
    public string fullName { get; set; } 

}
```

Then I need to write this class into.cs file inside any location in the system.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Where is your code, which you've tried?

Comment: C# is statically-typed, you can't meaningfully create new types at runtime. Please think  things through about what you actually need to achieve.

Comment: You want to create a class in. Cs file and then I use it in the same project as the current code is running?

Comment: No, I just want to create a class in. Cs file in a location specified by me

Comment: To rule out any language or terminology problems, maybe you can explain why you need this and how you would use it?

Comment: I need to check the response of some API's using Rest Sharp. I don't want to create a class beforehand for deserializing the JSON to object of the Class. Instead, I want to create the class during run time and store the class in a.Cs file from which I used the class for deserializing the JSON

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dynamically create a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862226/how-to-dynamically-create-a-class)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you do not know how to use reflection then do not use it. Especially if you do not need to load the class definition into the executing process.

What you could do is just process the json object with a library, token by token and write everything into a .cs file. These classes are simple enough that you do not need much work. A few switch statements should do the trick, the rest could be constant strings.

I recommend trying out the good old Newtonsoft.Json library:
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JTokenReader.htm
You can iterate through the document, switch on the type and then use some string magic to put the properties together.