# System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: '?' when trying to build a custom dynamic type with a delegate method

Tags: c#, .net-core, reflection.emit, .net-6.0

I am trying to dynamically build a type with a method that calls into an external delegate by using `System.Reflection.Emit`. However when I try to call this method, my program crashes with the exception in the title at the method call. Here's my code so far:

```cs
private static void TestMethodReal() => Console.Out.WriteLine("Inside TestMethod");

// In Main()
var method = typeof(Program).GetMethod(nameof(TestMethodReal), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic)!;

var builder = MyTypeBuilder.GetTypeBuilder("TestType");
var testMethod = builder.DefineMethod("TestMethod", MethodAttributes.Public, typeof(void), Type.EmptyTypes);

var generator = testMethod.GetILGenerator();
generator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, method, null);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

dynamic inst = Activator.CreateInstance(builder.CreateType()!)!;
inst.TestMethod(); // <--- Exception is thrown here
```

The `MyTypeBuilder` class and `GetTypeBuilder` method is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3862241/3314466) answer, slightly modified to accept a parameter for the type's name.

This program is supposed to create a new dynamic class with a method called `TestMethod` that calls the actual `TestMethodReal` method, instantiate the class, and call the method.

What am I missing?

Comment: This is strange `BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic)!;`. What is that `!` for?. And again in the line just before your error `Activator.CreateInstance(builder.CreateType()!)!;`

Comment: It's a somewhat annoying feature of one of the new C# versions (9.0 or 10.0 I believe). `GetMethod` returns a nullable `MethodInfo?` type (note the '?' at the end). The `!` basically ensures that the return value is not null, otherwise my IDE will complain about it and draw an ugly yellow squiggly line underneath it. Same with `CreateType` and `CreateInstance`, returning nullable `Type?` and `object?` types respectively.

Comment: Call the target method directly instead of requesting virtual dispatch: `generator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, method, Types.EmptyTypes)` - you don't need the runtime to resolve `TestMethodReal` for you since you already have an exact reference to it via `method` :)

Comment: Are you sure you are running on .NET 6 / .NET Core cause [`AppDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.definedynamicassembly?view=netframework-4.8) used in linked answer is .NET Framework only.

Comment: @GuruStron I forgot to mention this, but the .NET Core replacement of that method is [AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilder.definedynamicassembly?view=net-6.0), which I also replaced in the linked `GetTypeBuilder` method.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank you, this seems to have solved my problem for now. If you move your comment to an answer, I'll upvote it :)

Comment: Have you considered giving up dynamic type building and creating a direct delegate to the method `(Action)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong dispatch mechanism!

`OpCodes.Callvirt` is for *virtual* method calls, eg. overridable instance methods, the resolution of which needs to be deferred until runtime.

For static method invocation you'll want a plain old `OpCodes.Call` instruction instead:

```
generator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, method, Types.EmptyTypes);
```